# Meteor Facebook login missing appsecret_proof argument

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-oauth

Installed and configured `accounts-ui` and `accounts-facebook` modules. When I click on the login button for Facebook, I get an error:

> W20151003-14:05:14.378(-4) (oauth_server.js:398) Error in OAuth
>   Server: Failed to fetch identity from Facebook. failed [400]
>   {"error":{"message":"API calls from the server require an
>   appsecret_proof
>   argument","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"EXb0O+KXbNg"}}
>   I20151003-14:05:14.575(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'login'
>   Error: Failed to fetch identity from Facebook. failed [400]
>   {"error":{"message":"API calls from the server require an
>   appsecret_proof
>   argument","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"EXb0O+KXbNg"}}
>   I20151003-14:05:14.575(-4)?     at getIdentity
>   (packages/facebook/facebook_server.js:99:1)

I do have `Require app secret for server API calls` set to True in the advanced settings for the FB app for security reasons. When disabled, this works just fine. How can I make this work? I'm also confused by the fact that this is supposed to be a client-side operation. Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: Haven't really found an answer, but turning off "require app secret" in facebook settings fixes this for me (https://developers.facebook.com/apps//{app_id}/settings/advanced/) - More info https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2269 and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4441#issuecomment-106036295